# Mongo Db driver C# aggregation for update

Tags: c#, mongodb

How to create a new field (String) from value of another existing field (NubmerLong) for all documents in the collection via C# driver?
There is no problem using Mong Shell:

```
db.getCollection("MyCollection").updateMany(
  { },
  [{ $set: { recordId: { $toString: "$id" } } }]
)
```

Mongo driver has UpdateDefinitions and has PipelineDefinitions. And no compatibility between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to merge approaches Update + Pipeline for C# driver:

```
var stage = new BsonDocument { { "$set", new BsonDocument { { "recordId", new BsonDocument { { "$toString", "$id" } } } } } };
var pipeline = PipelineDefinition<BsonDocument, BsonDocument>.Create(stage);
...
Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Pipeline(pipeline)
```

Comment: It should be mentioned as well that with latest version 2.10.4 of stable MongoDB driver, it seems there is no way to use multiple pipeline stages or a combination of an update definition with a pipeline definition through an update query. Such cases produce bson array which cannot be processed by the MongoDB driver through an update query.

Comment: @e2l3n yep, I get this error: `System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonArray' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument'.`