# Update data type of field for all document using MongoDB C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to update the data type of a field from string to ObjectId for all documents in a collection using MongoDB C# driver. This query works perfectly fine:

```
db.getCollection('MyCollection').updateMany(
    { MyField: { $type: 2 } },
    [{ $set: { MyField: { $toObjectId: "$MyField" } } }]
);
```

But I'm struggling to write the same query in C#.
I've tried the following query using UpdateManyAsync:

```cs
var filter = new BsonDocument("MyField", new BsonDocument("$type", BsonType.String));
                var update = new BsonDocument {
                    { "$set", new BsonDocument("MyField", new BsonDocument("$toObjectId", "$MyField")) }
                };
var updateResult = await collection.UpdateManyAsync(filter, update);
```

But got the following error:

> The dollar ($) prefixed field '$toObjectId' in 'MyField.$toObjectId' is not valid for storage

This example here works, but it's not ideal because it forces me to fetch all documents:

```cs
var updateList = new List<WriteModel<BsonDocument>>();
var documents = await collection.Find(Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Empty).ToListAsync();

foreach (var document in documents)
{
    var id = document.GetElement("_id").Value.AsString;
    var myFieldValue = document.GetElement("MyField").Value.AsString;

    var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", id);
    var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set("MyField", new BsonObjectId(ObjectId.Parse(myFieldValue)));
    updateList.Add(new UpdateOneModel<BsonDocument>(filter, update));
}

if (updateList.Any())
{
    var bulkWriteResult = await collection.BulkWriteAsync(updateList);          
}
```

Comment: As understand from the first code and second. You have $toObjectId in first one and $toString in the next one. Maybe it causes an error?

Comment: Oops, that is a typo. I'm going to edit the question to fix that.

Comment: Done, fixed the code examples. Sorry for that

Comment: Did you tried to pass toObjectId without $?

Comment: @kanils_ if I remove the dollar sign from $toObjectId the field value is transformed to this:
 "MyField" : { "toString" : "$MyField" }

Comment: Are you actually need `MyField" : { "$toObjectId" : "$MyField" }` ?

Comment: Could work proper? Check please.
`var update = new BsonDocument ("$set", new BsonDocument("MyField", new BsonDocument("$toObjectId", "$MyField")));`

Comment: @kanils_ I got the same error message:
"The dollar ($) prefixed field '$toObjectId' in 'MyField.$toObjectId' is not valid for storage."

Comment: Found some info, could be helpful actually.
https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongoerror-the-dollar-prefixed-field-cond-in-energy-cond-is-not-valid-for-storage/16448#:~:text=%5B%20%7B%20%24set%3A%20%7B%20energy%3A%20%7B%20%24cond%3A%20%7B

Comment: Thank you @kanils_! You pointed me in the right direction! Check my answer below, please. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code example works:

```
var filter = new BsonDocument("MyField", new BsonDocument("$type", BsonType.String));
var stage = new BsonDocument { { "$set", new BsonDocument { { "MyField", new BsonDocument { { "$toObjectId", "$MyField" } } } } } };
var pipeline = PipelineDefinition<BsonDocument, BsonDocument>.Create(stage);
var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Pipeline(pipeline);

var result = await collection.UpdateManyAsync(filter, update);
```

Many thanks @kanils_ you pointed me in the right direction, this example [Mongo Db driver C# aggregation for update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61025449/mongo-db-driver-c-sharp-aggregation-for-update) also helped me to write the code above. Also many thanks @dododo for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Check this:

```
        var pipeline = Builders<BsonDocument>
            .Update
            .Pipeline(new EmptyPipelineDefinition<BsonDocument>()
                .AppendStage<BsonDocument, BsonDocument, BsonDocument>("{ $set: { MyField: { $toObjectId: '$MyField' } } }"));
        coll.UpdateMany(
            new BsonDocument("MyField", new BsonDocument("$type", BsonType.String)),
            pipeline);
```